# The ark of Covenant

Tags: biblical-basis, church-history, old-testament, exodus, golden-rule

When the children of Israel walked with Moses in the wilderness they had an ark that contained the rod, pot of manna, and the tablets. When they got to Canaan those things were no longer working.

My question is, didn't they attempt to try and use them again? Like to turn the rod into a snake in the promised land and so on?

Comment: It was God's ark. It still worked (see in the days of Samuel when many perished just for looking inside it). It was for God to say when supernatural things were to occur and when not. (It wasn't a 'magic' ark.)

Comment: My Question is: after the wilderness, did anyone try to use the rod or the manna? And did that work? I'm talking about whats inside the ark

Comment: _There was nothing in the ark save the two tables of stone_ 1 Kings 8:9 and 2 Chronicles 5:10.

Comment: "When they got to Canaan those things were no longer working." Do you have a specific reference for this?

Comment: The bible says "when they got to the borders of Canaan the manna ceased" exodus 16:30

Comment: . . . .  because Canaan was 'flowing with milk and honey' and manna was  no longer required.

Comment: You might find helpful information about this from the chosen answer to this question: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/64317/what-happened-to-aarons-staff-and-the-jar-of-manna-placed-by-moses-in-the-ark-o

Answer (score 2):

#### God tends to provide things for a purpose.

From a Pentecostal/Charismatic perspective, and speaking in more general terms (ignoring any inaccuracies about the contents of the Ark):

When God provides miracles, He tends to do so for a particular purpose. He's not some sort of robot where prayer goes in and miracle comes out. If you ask God to perform a miracle for the sake of performing a miracle, He'll probably say no; if you ask Him to perform a miracle for selfish purposes, He'll almost definitely say no - and He can read your mind, so He can tell why you *really* want a miracle.

When the Israelites were wandering the desert, they had no food or water  so God provided them for them through the miracle of manna - and He commanded then to gather only what they needed each day, forbidding hoarding of resources. Once they arrived in the promised land of milk and honey, they'd have no longer needed the miraculous provision of food and water, since their new land amply provided for them - and to ask for the miraculous provision to resume would have been an act of greed, laziness, or distrust in the truth of God's promises about the bountiful nature of their new land.

Similarly, Moses turning his rod into a snake was a one-time event that was performed for fulfilling a specific part of God's plan. The rod itself had no special powers; it was only able to turn into a snake through the active intervention of God.

God could, did, and still does continue to perform miracles, but it's important to remember that these miracles are performed in accordance to His will and purposes.