# If you die when you touch the ark how did the Philistines able to raid the ark cause the rod and the manna were missing when Solomon built the temple?

Tags: textual-discrepancies, 1-samuel, ark-of-the-covenant

When were Aaron's budded rod and the golden jar of manna still with the ark?  When Solomon built his temple the only thing in the ark was the stone tablets.  But if the Philistines took them, how would the Philistines able to open the ark if you died touching it?

Comment: I edited your question for clarity.  If you meant differently, please edit it yourself.

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/64317/what-happened-to-aarons-staff-and-the-jar-of-manna-placed-by-moses-in-the-ark-o mention the possibility that both the rod and manna isn't continuously kept inside since the ark is usually kept closed but the rod and manna is to be shown to the people

Comment: A careful reading of the passages in Kings and particularly Hebrews indicates that there was nothing in the ark except the stone tablets of the law. The other items were in the _tabernacle_ but not inside the ark.

Comment: The Philistines carried the ark off and then, when they opened it, it melted their faces off.

Comment: In seriousness, this appears to be a duplicate of this question: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/64317/what-happened-to-aarons-staff-and-the-jar-of-manna-placed-by-moses-in-the-ark-o

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happened to Aaron's staff and the jar of manna placed by Moses in the Ark of the Covenant](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/64317/what-happened-to-aarons-staff-and-the-jar-of-manna-placed-by-moses-in-the-ark-o)